# Does anyone know if there is an eclipse plugin can point out incompatible jars in pom.xml?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, plugins, pom.xml

Every decent sized Java EE contains tons of jar files. But what really annoys me is that you have to match different jar files version properly. For example, when using joda-time 2.2 with hibernate-entitymanager, if I choose hibernate-entitymanager 4.2.2 Final, then I will get this weird exception:

```
"java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime.nullSafeGet(Ljava/sql/ResultSet;[Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/hibernate/engine/spi/SessionImplementor;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;".
```

Then if I choose hibernate-entitymanager 3.6.8 Final, then everything works fine. I am wondering if there is a plugin can auto-detect incompatible jar files in the pom.xml editor (ex. gives warning or highlights incompatible jars) and suggest compatible versions?

Answer (score 1):

I found the [maven-dependency-versions-check-plugin](https://github.com/ning/maven-dependency-versions-check-plugin) on Github when I did a Google search.  It looks well thought out, and the documentation looks pretty comprehensive.  (Nice!)

Note that the documentation *says* you will need to build it from a source checkout ... but I actually found the plugin in [Maven Central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ning.maven.plugins/maven-dependency-versions-check-plugin).

It is also not clear how well it will work in practice.  For a start, it can only be as good as the dependency compatibility information that is included in the respective POM files.

Comment: Thanks, Stephen. I am gonna give it a try.